# In Rails, how do i keep before_create and using validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My code like this:

```
validates :user, presence: true
before_create :set_user   
def set_user
  self.user = current_user
end
```

I know `before_create` doesn't work but I need before action get user data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the before_action helper only on the actions you want.

```
before_action :set_user, only: :create
```

You can use an array to do this on more actions or use the `except: :some_stage` to exclude stages.

Comment: I'm guessing the code is in the model, not the controller and his issue is that the validation fires before the callback is called.

Comment: My user data maybe is nil, i just want logger the true user data, so  i need the validates.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it `before_validation` but to be honest I think that's the wrong solution too.

I would create whatever it is through the association.

```
class User
  has_one :foo
  has_many :bars
end
```

In the controller either

For `has_one`:

```
def new
  @foo = current_user.build_foo
end
```

For `has_many`:

```
def new
  @bar = current_user.bars.new
end
```

Comment: It'll need to be in `create`, not really a help in `new`.

Comment: @Swards should be in both really.

Comment: I would only put it in create.  It should be set in the controller just as you have.  Why would you put it in new?

Comment: Well I'd probably consider doing it in a `before_action` I was only illustrating above, using it through the association

Comment: Yeah - there's no reason to put it in new. Unless you want it in the form, but that column we want to set in the controller.